# Can you overload a function based on a destructured parameter?

Tags: typescript, types

[This example code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAaghgGwK4QEoQI5IJYCcIC2EAdsFALwBQUUAPlAOQByA9sRA9XYwILEhQAysFzZiAc0416DPgKZICAIwi4p3WcRbAAFqqgB1bABNxEYAB0GAZ1iIUDANyVKoSIZNmy5KAG8uAG72EABcUNYiYuKUAL4ubtBGpubwCCZwwNhsqEgI0D7%20NADunuZhSV4ANIHB6Fh4hCTAYakodTj4RKTVcZQAZkjEAMaZbFDY1jwKyqoAFEHIoeGREgCUYUosLHlwxH5curgsRVDsJwCiuEe4swBEAGKDI1l7WmTYBGB5XcAQxgB0t1Wzl6A2Goz2C3Sv1mJWSwFS0JeOTy5VKCMQSOyuQg6ygARYJn2NGsJWAQx0UFh6MRxgyyJx-wWbUwHUapFWxJoUCGcGs0GYbA4IS43Kg%20GASFwxFFPL5ArkUGmKjUIrFNGwfSpAEIJlNFCrqfDafTsXl-nCvEzgqtOYV1TRDsdThALlcWDdmHAmAxgbKaHEHRKpTKxQB6MNQf7RrhxXpAA) is somewhat contrived, but I'm trying to do something similar to it:

```
type ValueRequirement =
  | 'None'
  | 'Any String'
  | 'Any Number'
  | 'Another Widget\'s Value';

type Widget = {
  value: string
}

type WidgetValidationRule = {
  widget: Widget,
  valueRequirement: ValueRequirement,
}

function isANumber(value: string): boolean {
  throw new Error("Function not implemented."); // irrelevant implementation. Just trying to provide an example that can compile
}

function validate(widgetValidationRule: WidgetValidationRule): void {
  switch (widgetValidationRule.valueRequirement) {
    case 'None':
      return
    case 'Any Number':
      if (!isANumber(widgetValidationRule.widget.value)) {
        throw new Error('NaN');
      }
      return
    // ...
  }
}
```

I've been slowly adding more values to `ValueRequirement`, and I just added a new one, `'Another Widget\'s Value'`. For this, I realize I can't actually check if this is valid or not unless `validate` is passed a list of all other `Widget`s that exist.

On one hand, I could just add `allWidgets: Widget[]` as an optional parameter and throw a runtime exception if it is undefined if and only if the `ValueRequirement` is `'Another Widget\'s Value'`.

What I'd rather have is a compile time error: if `ValueRequirement` is `'Another Widget\'s Value'`, then a list of all other `Widget`s must be passed in as an additional parameter. Otherwise, it can't be passed in. [I imagine the solution would look something like this](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAaghgGwK4QEoQI5IJYCcIC2EAdsFALwBQUUAPlAOQByA9sRA9XYwILEhQAysFzZiAc0416DPgKZICAIwi4p3WcRbAAFqqgB1bABNxEYAB0GAZ1iIUDANyVKoSIZNmy5KAG8uAG72EABcUNYiYuKUAL4ubtBGpubwCCZwwNhsqEgI0D7%20NADunuZhSV4ANIHB6Fh4hCTAYakodTj4RKTVcZQAZkjEAMaZbFDY1jwKyqoAFEHIoeGREgCUYUosLHlwxH5curgsRVDsJwCiuEe4swBEAGKDI1l7WmTYBGB5XcAQxgB0t1Wzl6A2Goz2C3Sv1mvhKyWAlSgCzamA6jVIYU02j0uA8CKstlaHBi5VKwFS0JeOTySMQCAq5msZIRAG0ALrrZEsEzOMHPMZQ4wZCCw%20FVZG1NENH5Y1jsBgaORCFaSJX8KDTFRqUn4ryU4UQmkQLkBHnGPlPCGStKG0XilKIKnZXJLRkUp2G6muukIBnk6wAfhZXg5pvN%20xoAHoox8vrEXEA), but I can't figure out a way to get it to compile:

```
type ValueRequirement =
  | 'None'
  | 'Any String'
  | 'Any Number'
  | 'Another Widget\'s Value';

type Widget = {
  value: string
}

type WidgetValidationRule = {
  widget: Widget,
  valueRequirement: ValueRequirement,
}

function isANumber(value: string): boolean {
  throw new Error("Function not implemented.");
}

function validate({widget, valueRequirement: 'Another Widget\'s Value'}: WidgetValidationRule, allWidgets: Widget[]): void;
function validate({widget, valueRequirement: 'None' | 'Any String' | 'Any Number'}: WidgetValidationRule): void;
function validate(widgetValidationRule: WidgetValidationRule, allWidgets?: Widget[]): void {
  //impl
}
```

There are a lot of similar questions about overloading in general, but in this case, I would have to destructure a type and know its `ValueRequirement` value to overload.

I've been reading the handbook on how to [destructure objects](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/variable-declarations.html#destructuring) and [function overloading](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#function-overloads), but they don't mention this kind of use case. I'm not sure if that means it's not possible, I'm reading the wrong part of the docs, or this is a very unusual question that few have ever asked (I tried googling for this before writing this).

The title of [Destructuring with function overloading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54210528/destructuring-with-function-overloading) seems similar, but it's about destructuring inside the implementation. I'm talking about destructuring the function signature itself.

In typescript, can you overload a function based on a destructured parameter?

---

I think I'm going to move `ValueRequirement` from `WidgetValidationRule` to the `validate` function as a parameter. Then this seems straightforward. Regardless, I'm curious about the answer to this question.

Comment: Does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/wEGk2m) meet your needs?  I'm not sure whether you really care about overloads or destucturing since your example code shows neither.  I made an attempt to give a "destructured call signature" but there are no actual overloads.  Or you can overload but then you don't need destructuring.  And in neither case will the implementation be able to understand the correlation between the `ValueRequirement` property and the presence/absence of another function parameter...

Comment: ...If you really need something that works from the call and the implementation sides, you want a discriminated union like [this](https://tsplay.dev/mZblKm).  If you want me to write any of this up as an answer, let me know.  If I'm missing something, please [edit] the question to provide a true [mre] that tries to demonstrate what you're going for.

Comment: @jcalz Thanks for the help, but jsejcksn's answer was exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: So where's the destructuring in that answer?  What am I missing here?

Comment: @jcalz fair point. It's not there. I *thought* the solution to my problem would require destructuring. Apparently it doesn't.  I wrote some non-compiling code above to say the type of solution I assumed I needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this goal by making `WidgetValidationRule` generic (with a default parameter so that you can continue to use it as you do now), and then discriminating the parameter types in an overload based on the generic:

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noUncheckedIndexedAccess=true&target=99&useUnknownInCatchVariables=true&exactOptionalPropertyTypes=true#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-2sdgMEMxOGOKBWqAsADWLrVRw9UC9wDCvl9pIDMeDoZmHQjzTCAAM+ByGVybCyINW4wnky9cLgWAzDgAmADMfb7cIzMtx7qGd3zhf9gYYpamYYr-wWUFrIPpjPMTZ+rdiQL5BeC-r0CAQLAXQOPbX9gx7CGMC6FieTacoQA)

```ts
type ValueRequirement =
  | 'None'
  | 'Any String'
  | 'Any Number'
  | 'Another Widget\'s Value';

type Widget = {
  value: string
};

type WidgetValidationRule<T extends ValueRequirement = ValueRequirement> = {
  widget: Widget;
  valueRequirement: T;
};

function validate(widgetValidationRule: WidgetValidationRule<Exclude<ValueRequirement, 'Another Widget\'s Value'>>): void;
function validate(widgetValidationRule: WidgetValidationRule<'Another Widget\'s Value'>, otherWidgets: Widget[]): void;
function validate(widgetValidationRule: WidgetValidationRule, otherWidgets?: Widget[]): void {
  // implement
}

validate({
  widget: {value: 'one'},
  valueRequirement: 'None',
}); // ok

validate({
  widget: {value: 'one'},
  valueRequirement: `Another Widget's Value`,
});// Error (2322)

validate({
  widget: {value: 'one'},
  valueRequirement: `Another Widget's Value`,
}, [{value: 'hello'}, {value: 'world'}]); // ok
```

You might also split your union type into logical groups also to make it more readable:

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noUncheckedIndexedAccess=true&target=99&useUnknownInCatchVariables=true&exactOptionalPropertyTypes=true&ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=23&pc=2#code/C4TwDgpgBAkgdgEwpRE7AGoEMA2BXCAJQgEc8BLAJwgFs1goBeAKCigB8oByAOQHs4ELqw7cAgnBBQAysErk4Ac2FtOXCVJ54aAIwiUuAbmbNQkKABFkaJOmz4ipCtTrom4uH2AALfVADq5AiKEMAAOlwAzlD2BEYmZtCxjmRUtPTu8Egotpi4BMSpLhmcVjn0yYXO6ejGpuDQgcGh7gDeIgBu+RAAXFCRcgqKzAC+dYkBQSF5OEFYwOQChHg4EAA8ACpQEAAewDbRlU5prgyMMd1VJ-QAfG0iAO5ToX1N08ZsXQ5Xxeh9G8YxiYAGZ4OAAYwWAigXzm+wAFE9mjM4Ys4MtVq9niiEPM0Rj1llrKg7Jdjr9gDcAJR9Dp8ILGUEQqFwGG4OEQRHY+yopYrXqTZE83EsglrMo2Cpkoo1SkAGigXl8lDeoUiWORAG0ALo0mH0hCMsGQtFs2YizlI6bCvF8zGC63skX4-kKpX6VXASIAfg10x1erpQSg7TYAHow1ByDQwKtTqMTLCLfDQ1ArS8Q18CH0uAIhCM5Z1pdVTjn+IIuIWRlTDFAI4qANaJp3zTmp9PAPqtLMC3MVgtF77k2V9AAGEndlAdoSiFwco6rNfrAFFKJQ+FP4QAmADMW63VOb5tbKce2K7PZzea4A8+xeufyg488Pj8ntnyQXowVmu73Rzvg4DgfA3gqf4ODmDwbjgCA3rqtb1nwTZAA)

```ts
type IndependentValueRequirement =
  | 'None'
  | 'Any String'
  | 'Any Number';

type DependentValueRequirement = 'Another Widget\'s Value';

type ValueRequirement = IndependentValueRequirement | DependentValueRequirement;

type Widget = {
  value: string
};

type WidgetValidationRule<T extends ValueRequirement = ValueRequirement> = {
  widget: Widget;
  valueRequirement: T;
};

function validate(widgetValidationRule: WidgetValidationRule<IndependentValueRequirement>): void;
function validate(widgetValidationRule: WidgetValidationRule<DependentValueRequirement>, otherWidgets: Widget[]): void;
function validate(widgetValidationRule: WidgetValidationRule, otherWidgets?: Widget[]): void {
  // implement
}
```

Comment: Interesting! Is this considered a hack or idiomatic?

Comment: Idiomatic. A little generic abstraction can go a long way. I'll update the answer with a clarifying refactor in a minute.

Comment: thanks! For what it's worth, I understand your solution and I was planning on dividing the type like you suggested in your second answer